# Is a c-style cast calling an explicit conversion constructor correct?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, standards

Can a c-style cast call an explicit conversion constructor?

Consider the following code:

```
class Vec3
{
public:

    explicit Vec3(float All) 
        : X(All), Y(All), Z(All)
    {
    }

    Vec3(float InX, float InY, float InZ)
        : X(InX), Y(InY), Z(InZ)
    {
    }

    Vec3()
        : X(0), Y(0), Z(0)
    {
    }

    float X, Y, Z;
};

void Morph(const Vec3& In, Vec3& Out)
{
    Out = In;
}

int main(void)
{
    float Array[3] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
    Vec3 Morphed;
    Morph((const Vec3&)Array[0], Morphed);
}
```

On Microsoft VS2010's compiler, it converts the line `(const Vec3&)Array[0]` to a reinterpret_cast and a copy constructor to pass the parameter to the function.  Morphed gets a value of [1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f].

On another compiler from a third party, it converts `(const Vec3&)Array[0]` to a call to `explicit Vec3(float)` and then the copy constructor to pass the parameter to the function.  Morphed gets a value of [1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f].

I verified this by looking at the disassembly from both compilers:

VS2010:

```
   483:     float Array[3] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
0000000143E68049  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [__real@3f800000 (145DA1F18h)]  
0000000143E68051  movss       dword ptr [rsp+28h],xmm0  
0000000143E68057  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [__real@40000000 (145DC9704h)]  
0000000143E6805F  movss       dword ptr [rsp+2Ch],xmm0  
0000000143E68065  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [__real@40400000 (145DC9708h)]  
0000000143E6806D  movss       dword ptr [rsp+30h],xmm0  
   484:     Vec3 Morphed;
0000000143E68073  xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
0000000143E68076  movss       dword ptr [rsp+58h],xmm0  
0000000143E6807C  xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
0000000143E6807F  movss       dword ptr [rsp+5Ch],xmm0  
0000000143E68085  xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
0000000143E68088  movss       dword ptr [rsp+60h],xmm0  
   485:     Morph((const Vec3&)Array[0], Morphed);
0000000143E6808E  lea         rdx,[rsp+58h]  
0000000143E68093  lea         rcx,[rsp+28h]  
0000000143E68098  call        Morph (143E67FB0h)
```

Other compiler:

```
   184:     float Array[3] {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
0000000001E1F3B0  mov          rax,qword ptr [000000000432D1B0h] 
0000000001E1F3B7  mov          qword ptr [rbp-14h],rax 
0000000001E1F3BB  mov          edi,dword ptr [000000000432D1B8h] 
0000000001E1F3C1  mov          dword ptr [rbp-0Ch],edi 
   185:     Vec3 Morphed;
0000000001E1F3C4  lea          rdi,[rbp-130h] 
0000000001E1F3CB  call         Vec3::Vec3() (0000000003C119C0h) 
   186:     Morph((const Vec3&)Array[0], Morphed);
0000000001E1F3D0  lea          rdi,[rbp-140h] 
0000000001E1F3D7  vmovss       xmm0,dword ptr [rbp-14h] 
0000000001E1F3DC  call         Vec3::Vec3(float) (0000000003C119E0h) 
0000000001E1F3E1  lea          rdi,[rbp-140h] 
0000000001E1F3E8  lea          rsi,[rbp-130h] 
0000000001E1F3EF  call         Morph(Vec3 const&,Vec3&) (0000000001E1F350h)
```

Needless to say, this is causing many problems.  Which compiler is correct?  The third party code relies on Microsoft's implementation, but we are compiling with a different compiler for a different platform.

Comment: I'd say with high likelihood the very common VC compiler will be correct and not some third party compiler. Also, it seems wrong since the cast is to `(const Vec3&)` and not `(Vec3)`.

Comment: As far as the *standard* is concerned, converting a `const float &` into a `const Vec3 &` is undefined behavior. So either one is legit.

Comment: Fixing your problem is easy. Instead of type punning with C-style casts, change the cast to `static_cast<Vec>(Array[0])` and the constructor you desire will be called. Also, both GCC and clang behave the same as VC.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently fixing it. Unfortunately the code that's doing this is in a third party and is used often.  Luckily we have the source to edit.  The code expects the behavior of Microsoft's implementation.

Comment: @inflagranti Visual Studio "supports" many non-standard behaviors.

Comment: @Praetorian: How does the `static_cast` avoid UB? It still looks like UB to me.

Comment: @DavidHammen Wouldn't it invoke the single argument constructor? Kerrek had also posted similar verbiage in his (now deleted) answer.

Comment: @Praetorian - Now I see what you're going after. I didn't see the lack of an ampersand in your `static_cast<Vec>(Array[0])`. This is a well-defined conversion, not UB. It is however exactly not Chris wants.

Comment: @NeilKirk agreed, as does gcc. Still, I would generally trust the more common compiler for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the C++ *standard* is concerned, the conversion of a `float &` into a `const Vec3 &` is undefined behavior. Both compilers are right because the code is outside of the protection of C++.

If you want this to be a *protected* conversion, you have to stop the type punning and do a real copy of the `float` array into a `Vec3`.

Comment: Is it really UB? Since both are reference types they should have the same size, and as such, the C-style cast will (eventually) attempt and succeed with a `reinterpret_cast`. That brings it into implementation-defined territory.

Comment: @Praetorian: The `reinterpret_cast`ing of a reference to one type into a reference to another type which it is not layout compatible with yields *undefined behavior*. `float` and `Vec3` are not layout compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to the source code, do it right, where "right" means something that does not invoking undefined behavior. Add a conversion constructor to your class:

```
Vec3(const float* arr) : X(arr[0]), Y(arr[1]), Z(arr[2]) {}
```

Now you can call `Morph(Array, Morphed);` to "morph" that array to a Vec3, or even shorter, just use `Morphed = Array;`

Answer (score 0):

To fix the code, cast to `Vec3` instead of to `const Vec3&`. When casting to the reference, the subsequent creation of a `Vec3` wont allow explicit constructors.

Directly specifying the class type will directly create an object of it and allow explicit constructors to be used.